# How to put dictionary value into UITextView

Tags: swift, dictionary, ios8

I have a dictionary and need to put their value into `UITextView`, how to do that?

Comment: Your question is hopelessly vague. What does the dictionary contain? What key types, what value types? How do you want to format the contents of the dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary contains String,String. I want to format into String and put that into UITextView.

Comment: Sigh. Format how? We can't give you specific help unless you give us specific info.

Comment: I have a UITextView and it should put the value of the dictionary which I define. Dictionary is [String, String]. The value should be a String. Is this helpful?

Comment: Oh for @#$@ sake! What should the string look like? What keys do you want from the dictionary, and how do you want to present the contents of the dictionary in the resulting string, exactly and specifically? Is this just for debugging, for display to the user, or for some programming purpose?

Comment: It's an app, something like an encyclopedia about wood. I have a tableview in which the names of woods and when I click on one cell sends me to another controller where is a data about each species. On that side I have a picture and text. How to insert the text for each species?

Comment: I give up. You seem unable to define what you want to do coherently.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example for get values from dictionary:

```
var companies = ["AAPL" : "Apple Inc", "GOOG" : "Google Inc", "AMZN" : "Amazon.com, Inc", "FB" : "Facebook Inc"]
var allValues = [String]()
for (key, value) in companies {
    allValues.append(value)
}
allValues  //[Apple Inc, Amazon.com, Inc, Facebook Inc, Google Inc]
```

Now you can display `allValues` into your `UITextView` as per your need.